# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "{directory_name}"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run main.py from directory: /project/main.py, but I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'
```

My Overall Folder Structure:

```
|   main.py
|   
+---src
|   |   parameter.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|   +---data
|   |   |   types.py
|   |   |   __init__.py
|   |   |              
|           
\---tests
        test_parameter.py
        __init__.py
```

main.py code:

```py
from src import parameter
```

parameter.py code:

```py
from data import types
```

types.py code:

```py
print("Get Types data from here")
```

When I run parameter.py from directory: /project/src/parameter.py - it works. One thing I tried was changing the parameter.py import statement to be (below) - which fixed my problem in main.py, but then I couldn't run parameter.py separately. I want to be able to run parameter.py and main.py separately. Ideally, I want to avoid adding using "sys.path.append"

```py
from src.data import types
```

Any recommendations on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

```
from .data import types
```

Comment: When I run main.py it works, but when I run parameter.py, I get: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: @sapphire Why are you trying to run parameter.py?? Modules in packages are not meant to be run. If you want to run both main.py and parameter.py then don't make src a package and put main.py inside src.

Comment: Because I want to test parameter.py functionality separately, and main.py functionality separately. If I shouldn't run parameter.py, then how would I test it individually?

Comment: @sapphire I think you are fundamentally misunderstanding how packages and imports are supposed to be used. If it is a package, then being able to run it is not a part of the functionality. Packages modules are supposed to function as imports. You wouldn't test a musician by asking them to play football so why are you testing a package by trying to run it?

Comment: ok, parameter.py perhaps might not be a package, but it is rather a helper for main.py. What would you suggest be a good way (in terms of file structure) to organize helpers? Because, I have another “main_2.py”, where I use “parameter.py” in a different context/manner.

Comment: @sapphire can you describe to me what you mean by a helper? How exactly are parameter and main related?

Comment: Parameter.py contains a class, which main.py uses. The class in parameter.py is general which other modules can use, that’s why it is kept outside main.py. I thought of making a folder to keep such general classes ("helpers") and that is where I ran into ModuleNotFound issues.

Comment: @sapphire That sounds like a normal module to me. Why are you trying to run it? Generally, you should keep your class definitions and your run-able code in separate files.

Comment: I wanted to test parameter.py module functionality, so I had created a new folder called "tests" under src (directory: src/tests/test_parameter.py) - I tried running test_parameter.py directly, and I got a ModuleNotFoundError. (test_paramter.py had 1 line: "from src import parameter". I also did have __init__.py file inside the tests folder. So, that is why I am trying to run parameter.py and test its functionality inside parameter.py

Comment: @sapphire Ah ok I see, then you are not running parameter.py but running a different test file. Put your testing files in the same folder as your main.py and your problems should go away. Generally speaking, all the files you want to run should exist outside package folders.

Comment: I put the tests folder in same folder as main.py. I tried running test_parameter.py, but again got module error. Inside test_parameter.py I have: from src import parameter

My current structure now is: (edited my original post)

Comment: @sapphire No, put your test files in the same folder as main.py. All the files you want to run should be on the same level. And please read the relative imports link I posted in my answer. There are many other ways to do this as well if you read the documentation. The way I am suggesting is just what I myself and how I see other people doing it most often.

Comment: Ok, if I move test_parameter.py outside the tests folder, it does work. But I have other modules I need to test/run. Then, there be a mixture of "test_" modules and "normal" modules (like main.py). How would I get it to work, if I were to keep the "test_parameter.py" inside the tests folder, where the tests folder is same folder as main.py?

Comment: @sapphire please just read the documentation I linked in my original response. All the answers are in there if you try and understand them.